# Tree ID question from Los Angeles County, California

Tags: identification

[image: Leaves]

Can someone provide me with the family this tree belongs to? I have tried several tree ID keys, without success. It is located in Inglewood, California on a hospital campus planted next to *Melia azedarach*, *Ligustrum sinense*, and *Syzygium australe* in bare soil surrounded by a lawn.

The leaves are palmately compound with either 3, 4 or 5 leaflets. Margins are entire, green on both sides, smooth (not hairy), buds are above heart-shaped leaf scars. I didn't see any glands on the leaves.

[image: Bark]

[image: Flowers]

[image: Trunk]

Comment: Nice photos. Sierra Live Oak?

Comment: Not an oak, oaks have lobed, not palmate leaves.  Not sure what it is, though, but I will see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, have a look at this - [White Sapote (Casimiroa edulis)](http://growerjim.blogspot.com/2010/07/white-sapote-casimiroa-edulis.html).  It has palmate leaves, warty bark, flowers that look like the ones in your picture, and is hardy where ever citrus is able to be grown.  This would include most of the Southern California area.

Here is a link to [more pictures of this variety of sapote](https://www.google.com/search?q=warty%20bark%20tree&client=firefox-a&hs=IXn&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=np&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=hOZsU5flCJD3oAT28YBA&ved=0CDEQsAQ&biw=1417&bih=649#channel=np&q=Casimiroa%20edulis&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&tbm=isch).